# JBoss 7.4.4: Deploy applications after queues creation

Tags: jboss7.x, jndi, activemq-artemis, jboss6.x

I'm trying to update some applications of our company from a server with JBoss 6.3.3 to a server running JBoss 7.4.4.

Everything looks fine. The only problem is that my application is trying to use the JNDI object `java:/ConnectionFactory` before it is created. This makes the application fail.
After the application error (some time later) I am able to see into the logs that the queues are correctly bounded to the Jndi objects:

```
2023-07-04 10:21:59,782 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
```

I tried managing it at source code side but it generates side effects (new errors during start up and the need of supporting an specific branch of a custom library for this client).

The queue was defined in JBoss 6.3.3 in this way:

```xml
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.4">
            <hornetq-server>
                ...
                <jms-connection-factories>
                    <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                        <connectors>
                            <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                        </connectors>
                        <entries>
                            <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                        </entries>
                    </connection-factory>
                ...
                <jms-connection-factories>
                ...
            </hornetq-server>
        </subsystem>
```

But HornetQ is deprecated. In Jboss 7.4.4 the queue is defined in the `messaging-activemq` subsystem, in this way:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0">
  <server name="default" persistence-enabled="false">
      .....
    <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
      ......
  </server>
</subsystem>
```

It seems that `messaging-activemq` is a bit slower on starting up and queue generation that HornetQ.

In previous versions, when we had this error, we managed it using the `jboss-dependency.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency xmlns="urn:jboss:dependency:1.0">
    <item whenRequired="Real" dependentState="Create">org.hornetq:module=JMS,name="InVMConnectionFactory",type=ConnectionFactory</item>
</dependency>
```

But this is deprecated on JBoss 7.4.4

I have tried `jboss-all.xml` file, `jboss-deployment-dependencies.xml` file, and creating custom modules, but I'm not able to fix it.

What I need is that JBoss deploy my applications after that queue is created and the JNDI object (`java:/ConnectionFactory`) is bound to that queue. I checked the documentation, but I didn't seen anything.

How can I do it?

The JNDI object is looked up using `javax.naming.Context`, e.g.:

```java
Context ctx = new Context();
ConnectionFactory cf = ctx.lookup("java:/ConnectionFactory");
```

Into the `jboss-all.xml` I tried adding the dependencies using this format:

```xml
<jboss xmlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
    <jboss-deployment-dependencies xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0">
        <dependency name="DEPENDENCY" />
    </jboss-deployment-dependencies>
</jboss>
```

Instead of `DEPENDENCY` I tried:

- `org.wildfly.messaging.jms.queue.InVmConnectionFactory`
- `InVmConnectionFactory`
- `java:/ConnectionFactory`
- `org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq`
- The name of my custom modules
- Other random stuff when I didn't know what more trying.

Into the jboss-deployment-dependencies I tried adding the dependencies using this format:

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <resource-root path="DEPENDENCY" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Where `DEPENDENCY` was:

- `org.wildfly.messaging.jms.queue.InVmConnectionFactory`
- `InVmConnectionFactory`
- `java:/ConnectionFactory`

Also I tried removing the resource-root node and adding:

```xml
<module name="org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq" />
```

But I have had no success.

---

**UPDATE:**
It looks like they have removed the possibility of adding jboss dependencies  on queues and it should be controlled at source code level.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I edited the text and I added the answer to your questions at the end.

Comment: How is your application deployed? Is it in an EAR? What is your application? Is it a web application, EJB, etc.?

Comment: It is deployed with the deployment-scanner. Actually are two the apps affected by this. One of them is an ear, and the other one is a rar. The main app is just listening SOAP request and returning an answer to the client.